# ng-model not binding to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bind the value of a text input to a model value, but the value remains undefined...

The HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form name=user-form class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
      <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.formData.firstname" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="Firstname"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-offset-2">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Add" ng-click="ctrl.submit()">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
      controller: 'MainController',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    })
    .when('/user', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/user.html',
      controller: 'UserController',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    });
});

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('UserController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.formData = {};

    self.submit = function() {
      $http.post('http://localhost:50211/api/user/add',
      JSON.stringify(self.getUserData()))
      .success(function() {
        console.log('Success');
      })
      .error(function() {
        console.log('Failed');
      });
    };

    self.getUserData = function() {
      return {
        FirstName: self.formData.firstname
      };
    };

}]);
```

The data object for the ajax request always contains 'Firstname: undefined', I'm guessing I'm missing something simple but cant see it.

Comment: Why are you returning `FirstName: self.formData.firstname` not `FirstName: $scope.formData.firstname`

Comment: I tried this with no luck, still remains undefined...

Comment: @Matastic check the update in the answer.

Comment: What is this integer attribute? <input ... placeholder="Firstname" integer />

Comment: sorry integer shouldn't of been there.

Comment: I thought it could be some validation directive, so it could cause such problem

Comment: By the way, where do you check FirstName value? Do you set breakpoint in frontend javascript or you check value on backend in your http://localhost:50211/api/user/add?

Comment: I'm checking on the frontend.

Comment: How do you check it? Here is simplified codepen of your code, and looks like it works fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqXQJM?editors=1111  (open console to see results)

Comment: Also you don't need JSON.stringify() there

Comment: @svekl thanks a lot for creating that, I also tried to recreate my issue using plunkr [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/12s9jNq90H7cA3Tmlbws?p=info) and this also has an issue.

Comment: Your plunker has issue, you have ...ng-model="self.formData.firstname"..., but need to be ...ng-model="ctrl.formData.firstname"... and that's the only issue, binding works fine, so I guess you do some mistake, when you check what you get in ajax request